# Illustrator Split Words around TextWrap without Hyphen

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, text-wrap

I did some research for the text wrap that I am trying to achieve, as seen here:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the text is justified (Paragraph Option), and words are split up without hyphens. Minimum letter is as little as 1. How can I achieve this?

I've been able to use hyphenation, with minimum 3 letters. However, I want the split-up to be smaller, and I don't want the hyphen.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doable simply by *not* using hyphenation – only justification – and manually inserting word breaks using the space bar, which triggers the automatic justification to rewrap the text line. It can be quite laborious, but that's just how it is.

Just like when you manually correct the automatic hyphenation here and there, it's important to do the manual word break as the last step after all other settings are done. Work from top to bottom, and from right to left, to prevent the auto-justification to wrap finished lines again. The Single-Line Composer (corner menu of the Paragraph panel) is better to work with here because the All-Line Composer would just rewrap all lines. (Anyway, keep a copy of the unaltered text so that you can quickly start over again.)

Before starting the word breakup: use the Justification settings (via corner menu in the Paragraph panel). The goal is to balance out the justification to avoid large gaps between words and letters as good as possible, so that the text area has an even 'grey'. It can take some time to find the optimal setting…

[image: justification settings]
[image]
[image]

(The skull is a compound shape with holes – it was placed over the text box and set to wrap the text `Object > Text Wrap > Make`. In Text Wrap Options, offset value set to 0.) Words have been broken up using spaces to fill gaps so that the shape is.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to get rid of the hyphens, but tweaking some settings can generate a pretty tight Text Wrap:

[image]

The key for me was setting the Paragraph to use the **Adobe Every-line Composer** instead of the default **Adobe Single-line Composer** option.

Comment: Yes this is a tighter wrap, but I'm still looking for a way to break words even after 1 letter and without a hyphen, as seen in the original image. I know Illustrator was used for this. Thank you very much for your help, though.

Comment: About the only way I can think of to make Illustrator do this is by manually spacing the letters and not using a Text Wrap at all. I'm sure if @scott was around he'd be able to confirm or give a better solution.